# Download file from azure blob and coming empty pdf pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to upload file to azure blob, it is successfully uploading but when I download it then if it is PDF file then it has all pages coming blank and if it is excel file then getting this error.

```
Excel cannot open because file format or extension is not valid.
```

First of all I am getting response as string as per below, I am not sure whether I need to use UTF-8 or ASCII for endcoding.

```
var data = "PK\u0003\u0004\u0014\0\b\b\b\0�\\ZU\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\v\0\0\0_rels/.rels���j�0\f��}\n�{㴃1F�^Ơ�2�\a�l%1I,c�[��3�l\v\rl�����\u001fH��4\u000e�R�\u001c\fl�\u001a\u0014\u0005�·����q}\a*\v\u0006�\u0003\a2\u0010\u0018\u000e���\u0006���;\u001f�*��\rt\"�^�l;\..."
```

Now using that string I am creating memeory stream and then call function to upload it to blob.

```
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));
memoryStream.Position = 0;
    
var lastIndedOf = attachment.FileName.LastIndexOf(".");
var extension = attachment.FileName.Substring(lastIndedOf);
    
if (extension == ".pdf")
{
    FileStreamResult fileStreamResult = new FileStreamResult(memoryStream, "application/pdf");
 
    fileStreamResult.FileDownloadName = companyId + extension;
    
    var file = new FormFile(memoryStream, 0, memoryStream.Length, null, companyId + ".pdf")
    {
        Headers = new HeaderDictionary(),
        ContentType = "application/pdf"
    };
    var fileUploadData = await _azureBlobStorageService.SaveToFolderBlobStorage(file, companyId + ".pdf",
                                        companyId, companyId.ToString());
} 
else
{
    FileStreamResult fileStreamResult = new FileStreamResult(memoryStream, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
 
    fileStreamResult.FileDownloadName = companyId + extension;
    
    var file = new FormFile(memoryStream, 0, memoryStream.Length, null, companyId + ".xlsx")
    {
        Headers = new HeaderDictionary(),
        ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
    };
    
    var fileUploadData = await _azureBlobStorageService.SaveToFolderBlobStorage(file, companyId + "zoho" + ".xlsx",
                                        companyId, companyId.ToString());

    //Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
}
```

Comment: How are you getting the file?, for example if you have the link for the file you can use:
`var response = await client.GetAsync(tempPdfUrl)`,  and then `pdfBytes = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync()`, then you can convert the byte[] to memory stream

Comment: @CristinaCarrasco I am calling one API and it is returning this data.. this is code for that..
`var httpResponse = await _restClientService.GetAsync(new Uri(requestUrl), "", new Dictionary<string, string>());
var responseData = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();`

Comment: Instenad of `ReadAsStringAsync()` use `ReadAsByteArrayAsync()` the result will be `byte[]`, then use the variable directly in `new MemoryStream(responseData)`

Answer (score 0):

*Using namespace* `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage`

1. *Need to create a storage account and container in azure as shown below.*

[image]

[image]

*Using the below code snippet, we can download any file type from azure.*

```
string storageAccount_connectionString = "ConnectionString";
CloudStorageAccount storage_Account =   CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageAccount_connectionString);
CloudBlobClient blob_Client = storage_Account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = blob_Client.GetContainerReference(container_Name);
CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(filename);
Stream file = File.OpenWrite(@"C:\Tools\" + filename);
cloudBlockBlob.DownloadToStream(file);
Console.WriteLine("Download completed!");
```

*Uploaded the files in container*

[image]

*Downloaded the complete files of .pdf and .xlsx.*

[image]